# How to close a circuit using a level

Tags: circuit-design

First off, let me apologize if this question is too basic for the community - I've searched quite a bit for a solution, but wasn't able to locate anything.

I'm a hobbyist working on a project that would require a circuit to be closed when an object is out of bounds on an inclinometer (basically a curved level) .  I would like to use a rudimentary ball inclinometer (as pictured) over a more complex electronic solution.
[image]

I my goal is simple: close a circuit to activate a LED when there is more than a 5 degree bank - or alternatively, open a circuit when the ball leaves the +/- 5 degree range.  I can't seem to locate a device that would accomplish this goal commerically and would like to build it for my own use.  I'm stumped as to how to build this, though it seems as if it would be fairly simple.

My only other requirement is that the solution does not involve magnets, as it will be mounted on metal housing which could effect accuracy.

Thoughts?

Comment: Only problem I see with using a mercury switch is that the designs I've seen require the mercury to hit an extreme - i.e. one end or the other.  I would like to maintain full range, but create an indication that the incline is "out of normal range"

Comment: Use a tilt sensor and a micro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obvious way to build such a thing would be to start with two metal (conductive) plates with the curved slots cut into them.

Then mount the plates with an insulator between them, and a ball-bearing sitting in the slot between them.

Insulate the slot in the range from 0 to 5 degrees inclination.

Finally, you need an electrical connection to each plate. When the ball bearing is on the insulated section, there will be no connection between the plates. When the plates are tilted enough that the ball bearing sits on the un-insulated portion, it will complete a connection between the plates.

Comment: Ah yes, I understand what you're getting at.  If I mounted one conductor on the bottom of the inclinometer and the other on the top, insulated the top to the range I wanted, I could close the circuit quite easily!  This is why I love stackexhange!

Answer (score 1):

Pinball machines used to use a tilt bob. Image from [here](http://www.marcospecialties.com//images/products/PLBAS/detail.JPG)

[image]

The bob hangs down in the hole in the bracket, and tilting off vertical by more than a certain amount (adjustable by the vertical position of the bob) will allow it to touch the inside of the hole.

---

You can do a similar thing with an accelerometer, but it would probably require a cellphone style 3-axis unit, since \$\sin(5\cdot2\pi/360) \gt \gt 1-\cos(5\cdot2\pi/360)\$.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of [tilt sensors](https://learn.adafruit.com/tilt-sensor) mounted at just below 5° above horizontal in opposite directions should do what you need.

Comment: I like that thought, but I really wanted to maintain the original form an function of the inclinometer without additional hardware